# Symfony2: List all views / routing-files in virtual folder (Netbeans)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, netbeans, view

As I am recently working a lot with the TWIG Template Engine and 30 or more Views in one project, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the browsing process in Netbeans switching from Bundle to Bundle to get to other template files.

What I am looking for is something like a "views"- and "routing"-Navigator like the "Important Files"-Folder.

Has someone already written a folder structure for this issue? Is there maybe a plugin out there?

Or simply: How do **YOU** deal with this?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched from the Eclipse / Netbeans platforms to PHPStorm because of similar issues.  PHPStorm has Symfony2 framework integration that makes it extremely convenient to navigate a Symfony2 app with any number of bundles.  They also added in some really great code reformatting tools and composer integration.  Definitely worth looking into.

[JetBrains - PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)